# Is it possible for two people in the "middle" of the political spectrum to have opposite views?

Tags: united-states

If two people have equal amounts of opposing left and right views could they balance out to be in the same spot in the middle?

Comment: Your title doesn't make any sense compared to the question you are asking (in either case, it seems to be most opinion based and makes assumptions that the political spectrum is linear.)

Comment: For those voting to close - I believe this is a good and on-topic question because while basic, it is clearly about political theory, which is very on topic for this site

Comment: Define "balance out." How do you measure that?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - I'm unaware of anyone (at least first 4 VTCs) who closed because of offtopicness

Comment: Most of these questionnaires that assess your political leaning (including the political compass) ask for views on a range of issues and take an average of the results. So yes, being left on some and right on others will tend to put you in the centre.

Answer (score 3):

The political spectrum commonly referred to "left" and "right" is just an analogy. It is not a literal well defined spectrum with every position mapped out. Thus your concept of equal but opposite left and right views doesn't really make sense. There is no 'exact' middle, and you can not really quantify someone's position on the spectrum.

One common alternative to the political spectrum (aka the linear model) is know as the [political *compass*](https://www.politicalcompass.org/analysis2). This moves us from a 1 dimensional representation to a 2 dimensional representation where the 2 dimensions are economic and social issues.

[image]

In the model it is clear that the middle (now really a center) is not as easy to hit. And of course in reality there is no such thing as perfect center.

Comment: This is also a simplification of the reality.  I can easily think of 6 additional dimensions off the top of my head: Responsibility, morality, order, violence,  nationalism,  populism and i am sure you could chart a dozen more with a little effort

Comment: @SoylentGray Like I said, it is _one_ alternative. There are many others.

Comment: An example might be illustrative. ex.  Someone might be pro- Death penalty (a more "right" stance), and pro-choice/abortion (left stance) while someone else might be strictly Pro-Life in the Catholic sense (anti-abortion - right of center, anti-death penalty - left of center) - opposing viewpoints on both issues, but both in the "middle", in sum.

Comment: I understand my question is trying to cookie-cutter a very complex subject, and I still find it intriguing trying to define something that is not necessarily definable. It seems like peoples political stance is as unique as our DNA. PoleHoleSet your example is exactly what I was getting at. While the left and right in a traditional sense are somewhat clear, when someone's says "I'm in the middle" that's about as clear as mud when it comes to explaining your political views. Thanks for all your input.